# Grails different Json Marshaller depending on request origin

Tags: json, api, grails, marshalling

Currently i use a custom json marshaller to render a response, like illustrated in this [article](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/).

In this article they use one custom marshaller for each Domain Class. For example:
/books and /books/1 will give the same data representation.

What i want is a different rendering for those two. So that /books gives less detailed information than /books/1.

Does anyone know to chose a marshaller or alter the response based on the request that has been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Grails documentation you can register [named marshallers](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#namedObjectMarshallers). This way you can decide in your controller which marshaller to use. The documentation has some good examples of this as well.